# Vidyo native component in React-Native

Tags: java, android, react-native, video-conferencing

I have written an component using Vidyo sdk (Vidyo.io). Component was meant to be used in React-Native application and it was written 100% in java. The problem is that when I try to use this component in React it is not showing any video or camera preview. In 100% android application everything works correctly, as it is shown in demo application. To be sure I have checked several times if permission for camera is given - and it it. I have also checked if whole project have internet connection (and permission) - and it have

here is the code of xml file:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/video_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/endCallButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/red_round_border"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_end_call"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/changeCameraStateButton" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/connectProgress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/errorText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/changeCameraStateButton"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/grey_round_border"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_deactivate_camera"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/endCallButton" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and here is implementation on android side:

```
public class VidyoView extends ConstraintLayout implements
        VidyoConnector.IConnect,
        VidyoConnector.IRegisterLogEventListener,
        VidyoConnector.IRegisterNetworkInterfaceEventListener {

    private static final String TAG = "VidyoView";

    enum VIDYO_CONNECTOR_STATE {
        VC_CONNECTED,
        VC_DISCONNECTED,
        VC_DISCONNECTED_UNEXPECTED,
        VC_CONNECTION_FAILURE
    }

    private FrameLayout imageContainer;
    private ImageView endCallButton;
    private ProgressBar progress;
    private TextView errorText;

    private boolean vidyoClientInitialized = false;
    private VIDYO_CONNECTOR_STATE vidyoConnectorState = VIDYO_CONNECTOR_STATE.VC_DISCONNECTED;
    private VidyoConnector vidyoConnector = null;
    private boolean vidyoConnectorConstructed = false;
    private WeakReference<ThemedReactContext> reactContext;

    private String host;
    private String token;
    private String userName;
    private String resourceId;


    public VidyoView(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
        setUp();
    }

    public VidyoView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setUp();
    }

    public VidyoView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, @AttrRes int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        setUp();
    }

    private void setUp() {
        Log.d(TAG, "SET UP");
        inflate(getContext(), R.layout.component_vidyo_view, this);

        reactContext = new WeakReference<>((ThemedReactContext) getContext());

        setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        imageContainer = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.video_container);
        endCallButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.endCallButton);
        progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.connectProgress);
        errorText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.errorText);

        if(reactContext.get() != null) {
            Connector.SetApplicationUIContext(reactContext.get().getCurrentActivity());
        }

        vidyoClientInitialized = Connector.Initialize();

        endCallButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                stopConnection();
            }
        });
        start();
    }

    public void start() {
        ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = imageContainer.getViewTreeObserver();
        if (viewTreeObserver.isAlive()) {
            viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    imageContainer.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                    // If the vidyo connector was not previously successfully constructed then construct it
                    checkVidyoConnectionAndReconnect();
                    connect();
                }
            });
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void OnSuccess() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Success, connected");
        onConnectorStateUpdeted(VIDYO_CONNECTOR_STATE.VC_CONNECTED, "Connected");
        EventEmitter.emmitVidyoConnected(reactContext.get(), getId());
    }


    @Override
    public void OnFailure(VidyoConnector.VidyoConnectorFailReason vidyoConnectorFailReason) {
        onConnectorStateUpdeted(VIDYO_CONNECTOR_STATE.VC_CONNECTION_FAILURE, "Connected");
        EventEmitter.emmitVidyoConnectionFailure(reactContext.get(), getId(), vidyoConnectorFailReason.toString());
        Log.d(TAG, "On failure = " + vidyoConnectorFailReason.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void OnDisconnected(VidyoConnector.VidyoConnectorDisconnectReason vidyoConnectorDisconnectReason) {
        if (vidyoConnectorDisconnectReason == VidyoConnector.VidyoConnectorDisconnectReason.VIDYO_CONNECTORDISCONNECTREASON_Disconnected) {
            Log.d(TAG, "OnDisconnected: successfully disconnected, reason = " + vidyoConnectorDisconnectReason.toString());
            onConnectorStateUpdeted(VIDYO_CONNECTOR_STATE.VC_DISCONNECTED, "Disconnected");
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "OnDisconnected: successfully disconnected, reason = " + vidyoConnectorDisconnectReason.toString());
            onConnectorStateUpdeted(VIDYO_CONNECTOR_STATE.VC_DISCONNECTED_UNEXPECTED, "Unexpected disconnection");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void OnLog(VidyoLogRecord vidyoLogRecord) {

    }

    @Override
    public void OnNetworkInterfaceAdded(VidyoNetworkInterface vidyoNetworkInterface) {

    }

    @Override
    public void OnNetworkInterfaceRemoved(VidyoNetworkInterface vidyoNetworkInterface) {

    }

    @Override
    public void OnNetworkInterfaceSelected(VidyoNetworkInterface vidyoNetworkInterface,
                                           VidyoNetworkInterface.VidyoNetworkInterfaceTransportType vidyoNetworkInterfaceTransportType) {

    }

    @Override
    public void OnNetworkInterfaceStateUpdated(VidyoNetworkInterface vidyoNetworkInterface,
                                               VidyoNetworkInterface.VidyoNetworkInterfaceState vidyoNetworkInterfaceState) {

    }

    private void onConnectorStateUpdeted(VIDYO_CONNECTOR_STATE state, final String statusText) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectorStateUpdeted, state = " + state.toString());

        vidyoConnectorState = state;

        ThemedReactContext context = reactContext.get();
        if (context != null && context.getCurrentActivity() != null) {
            context.getCurrentActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (vidyoConnectorState == VIDYO_CONNECTOR_STATE.VC_CONNECTED) {
                        hideProgress();
                    } else if(vidyoConnectorState == VIDYO_CONNECTOR_STATE.VC_CONNECTION_FAILURE){
                        hideProgress();
                        errorText.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                        errorText.setText("Cannot load");
                        EventEmitter.emmitVidyoConnectionFailure(reactContext.get(), getId(), "cannot connect");
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    }

    public void setHost(String host) {
        Log.d(TAG, "SET HOST");
        this.host = host;
    }

    public void setToken(String token) {
        Log.d(TAG, "SET TOKEN");
        this.token = token;
    }

    public void setResourceId(String resourceId) {
        Log.d(TAG, "SET RESOURCE ID");
        this.resourceId = resourceId;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        Log.d(TAG, "SET USER NAME");
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public void connect() {
        if (vidyoConnectorState != VIDYO_CONNECTOR_STATE.VC_CONNECTED && vidyoConnector != null) {
            progress.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            if (!vidyoConnector.Connect(
                    host,
                    token,
                    userName,
                    resourceId,
                    this)) {
                onConnectorStateUpdeted(VIDYO_CONNECTOR_STATE.VC_CONNECTION_FAILURE, "Connection failed");
                Log.d(TAG, "Status: " + false);
            } else
                Log.d(TAG, "Status: " + true);
        }
    }

    private void checkVidyoConnectionAndReconnect() {
        if (!vidyoConnectorConstructed) {

            if (vidyoClientInitialized) {
                connectVidyo();

            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "ERROR: VidyoClientInitialize failed - not constructing VidyoConnector ...");
            }

            Log.d(TAG, "onResume: vidyoConnectorConstructed => " + (vidyoConnectorConstructed ? "success" : "failed"));
        }
    }

    private void connectVidyo() {
        vidyoConnector = new VidyoConnector(imageContainer,
                VidyoConnector.VidyoConnectorViewStyle.VIDYO_CONNECTORVIEWSTYLE_Default,
                15,
                "info@VidyoClient info@VidyoConnector warning",
                "",
                0);

        vidyoConnectorConstructed = true;

        refreshView();

        if (!vidyoConnector.RegisterNetworkInterfaceEventListener(VidyoView.this)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "VidyoConnector RegisterNetworkInterfaceEventListener failed");
        }

        if (!vidyoConnector.RegisterLogEventListener(VidyoView.this, "info@VidyoClient info@VidyoConnector warning")) {
            Log.d(TAG, "VidyoConnector RegisterLogEventListener failed");
        }
    }

    private void  hideProgress(){
        progress.setVisibility(GONE);
    }


    private void refreshView() {
        progress.setVisibility(GONE);
        vidyoConnector.ShowViewAt(imageContainer, 0, 0, imageContainer.getWidth(), imageContainer.getHeight());
    }

}
```

Does anyone knows what can cause this problem?

Comment: Did you try with a valid width/height on the frame layout? - 
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/video_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"

Comment: I was trying to set hard coded size for FrameLayout and it was also not working. I have found out that component is properly rendered after change orientation of the device. After call vidyoConnector.ShowViewAt there is created LmiWindow in Frame layout which has dimentions 0x0 till I rotate device. After rotation LmiWindow recalcualtes its dimentions and looks as it should (size consistent with FrameLayout size)